# How to network share a search in windows?

Tags: windows, networking, search

I have a search link in my windows explorer searching for all my movie files imported from my camera.  The files are spread across a lot of folders in My Pictures.  I would like to be able to make a network share from this search.  How could I simulate a folder that is actually a "search folder" for my movies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible without Windows Server 2008 and Sharepoint.

Since your saved search is technically a shortcut file, you can't turn it into a networks share.